Movie about getting lost in the woods, with unicorns on the ocean?
What is the movie called that is about a girl who is living at this castle type place with her uncle (I think) and he tells her not to go into the woods but she does obviously. And so in the woods these guys take her back to this facility of sorta and lock her up. She escapes.
And then later in the movie she goes back into the woods and sees one of the guys there trying to capture a rabbit and he wouldn't let it go, so the next day she set up a trap for him and he ended up hanging by his feet until he agreed to help her find these pearls for "mother nature". He agreed and they had to look in the woods for a certain tree. When they found the tree they could open the door and go inside the tree and she and the guy found the pearl necklace.
So they brought it to the ocean where she threw the necklace into the water. Mother nature sent it back in pieces and she had to jump into the water. No one there knew where she was until there was a big wave and a bunch of unicorns were riding it and she was on one. And there was a big black lion there too.

Is it animated?  It sounds similar to The last unicorn

Posted a possible match. Year & country often help in these type of questions, BTW.

You're looking for the fantasy film The Secret of Moonacre from 2008.

When 13 year old Maria Merryweather's father dies, leaving her orphaned and homeless, she is forced to leave her luxurious London life to go and live with Sir Benjamin, an eccentric uncle she didn't know she had, at the mysterious Moonacre Manor. Soon Maria finds herself in a crumbling moonlit world torn apart by the hatred of an ancient feud with the dark and sinister De Noir family. Maria discovers that she is the last Moon Princess and, guided by an unlikely mix of allies, she must overcome her family's pride in order to unearth the secrets of the past before the 5000th moon rises and Moonacre disappears into the sea forever.

It's all there (the pearl necklace thrown into the sea, the unicorn & black lion etc). Here's the trailer:



